# uWSGI and nginx serving static from Django

Tags: django, nginx

I've setup a django project to serve static with nginx and uses uwsgi also. While running in `debug = True` I can view a demo static file on the homepage and admin static is loading but when I set `debug = False` it fails to load static files, it returns a 404. I've set the permissions for the folder to 755 but it didn't resolve the issue.

Here's the settings in the settings file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'kb/media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'kb/static/'),]
```

nginx config file `kb_nginx.conf`

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/ubuntu/kb/kb.sock; # for a file socket
    #server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name kenyabuzz.nation.news; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/kb/kb/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/kb/kb/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ubuntu/kb/kb/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

symlinked as `sudo ln -s /home/ubuntu/kb/kb/kb_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Run it using `uwsgi --http :8000 --socket kb.sock --module kb.wsgi --chmod-socket=664`

**UPDATE**
Here's uwsgi runtime results:

```
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 16432, cores: 1)
[pid: 16432|app: 0|req: 1/1] 197.232.12.165 () {42 vars in 774 bytes} [Fri Jan  6 07:27:49 2017] GET / => generated 152 bytes in 11 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 3 headers in 102 bytes (2 switches on core 0)
[pid: 16432|app: 0|req: 2/2] 197.232.12.165 () {42 vars in 781 bytes} [Fri Jan  6 07:27:49 2017] GET /static/img/girl.png => generated 93 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 3 headers in 94 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Comment: 666 is not correct permissions, try 755.

Comment: Also tell us the error (is it 404 or 403?). Also, have you run `collectstatic`? And if you don't understand it clearly see this: http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/21/how-django-static-files-work-in-production/

Comment: Why are you trying to start uwsgi with both socket and http? Since you're binding to port 8000, and nginx is also trying to serve on that port, I doubt nginx will start at all, but even if it did you would be bypassing it.

Comment: I added http because it wasn't using port 8000, currently don't have access to port 80 (someone need to open the port for me later). I've tried now `uwsgi --http :8000 --module kb.wsgi` but still doesn't work and nginx isn't logging requests.